# Темнота на сцене при загрузке с SceneManager.LoadScene() Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Проблема в загрузке сцены - загружаемая сцена получается темной:
[image]
Хотя задумано быть такой (запустил сразу с этой сцены, а не через начальную):
[image]

Загружается обычно, с помощью:

```
SceneManager.LoadScene("Main");
```

С чем это связано и как это можно исправить?

Comment: [Оно?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42448608/12888024)

Answer (score 1):

Это баг движка, попробуй сбилдить проект и там все будет нормально освещаться. Сталкивался с такой же проблемой, когда работал с 3D приложением.
Фиксил, вроде, при помощи выключения авто-генерации света в настройках освещения проекта.